# Pandas correlation

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe structure:

```
                       roc_sector                roc_symbol
                       mean, max, min, count      mean, max, min, count
date,       industry
2015-03-15  Health     123, 675, 12, 6            35, 5677,  12,  7
2015-03-15  Mining     456, 687, 11, 9            54, 7897,  44,  3
2015-03-16  Health     346, 547, 34, 8            67, 7699,  23,  5
2015-03-16  Mining     234, 879, 34, 2            35, 3457,  23,  4
2015-03-17  Health     345, 875, 54, 6            45, 7688,  12,  8
2015-03-17  Mining     876, 987, 23, 7            56, 5656,  43,  9
```

What I need to do is calculate the correlation between the industries over x number of days. For example, I would need to see what the correlation is between the Health and Mining industry over the last 3 days for the roc_sector + mean.

I've been trying a few things with pandas df.corr() and pd.rolling_corr() but I haven't had any success because I can't seem to change the dataframe structure from what it is currently (as above), into something that will allow me to get the required correlations per industry, over x days.

Comment: You have problems accessing the columns ?

Comment: @fixxxer I think he needs to unstack the ``industry`` column in order to apply ``rolling_corr`` on the result.

Comment: @AmiTavory - maybe. But OP needs to clarify what he means by "I can't seem to change the dataframe structure"

Comment: @fixxxer if you apply df.corr() to the current structure, all you get is a correlation of all the columns, eg: correlation between mean and max. That is not what is required. I need to find the correlation between each industry. In other words the industries need to become columns (along with the existing columns), and the rows will be dates. I haven't had any luck doing that.

Comment: @fixxxer You might be right. It's what I inferred (I hope correctly) from the rest of the phrasing of the question.

Comment: @darkpool - you can use `pivot` to get the industries as columns and rows as indexes. I used a simplified version of your dataframe. Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by performing an appropriate [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) followed by a regular `rolling_corr`.

Start off by setting `industry` as the index (or part of the index). `unstack` the appropriate index level using the above link as an example. In the resulting dataframe, just use `rolling_corr` on the columns of the industry means.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are expecting to do ? Assume this df is your dataframe -

```
In [43]: df
Out[43]: 
         date industry  mean  max  min  count
0  2015-03-15   Health   123  675   12      6
1  2015-03-15   Mining   456  687   11      9
2  2015-03-16   Health   346  547   34      8
3  2015-03-16   Mining   234  879   34      2
4  2015-03-17   Health   345  875   54      6
5  2015-03-17   Mining   876  987   23      7

In [44]: x = df.pivot(index='date', columns='industry', values='mean')

In [45]: x
Out[45]: 
industry    Health  Mining
date                      
2015-03-15     123     456
2015-03-16     346     234
2015-03-17     345     876

In [46]: x.corr()
Out[46]: 
industry    Health    Mining
industry                    
Health    1.000000  0.171471
Mining    0.171471  1.000000
```

Comment: Seems about right. As a minor point, I think ``rolling_corr`` should end things off.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. @AmiTavory your solution worked and is what I am using. fixxer I can't get your solution to work with my dataframe structure, it only works with the simplified version you've shown above. But don't worry, using unstack is working correctly. Thanks.

Comment: what is *not* working correctly ? 
@AmiTavory - that's not the primary problem ?

Comment: @darkpool The choice of ``unstack`` vs. ``pivot`` depends on the index structure, in this case. I think that fixxxer's answer is a good one too.

Comment: @fixxxer Not sure what you mean - I liked your answer.

Comment: Trying the above solution gives me KeyError: 'mean'. Using unstack(level=-1) followed by the correlation works. Don't worry it's probably just me not using pivot correctly. Thanks to you both.

Comment: @AmiTavory - Thank you. I was just replying to your first comment about `rolling_corr`